# UITableViewController doesn't work properly in xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

Can anyone tell me, what am I doing something wrong?
I have created a quick project by selecting template *'Empty Application'*.
I created new controller with subclass **UITableViewController**.

I wrote below a piece of code to call the controller:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
 //   self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    MyTableViewController *mtvc = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [nav pushViewController:mtvc animated:YES];
    [self.window addSubview:nav.view];



    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and fill up UITableViewController's methods to check if it is working:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.text = @"test";

    return cell;
}
```

When I try to select the cell table the method  *didSelectRowAtIndexPath* doesn't call at all.

I am new in iphone programming so maybe I am doing something wrong?

---

I have posted problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827776/uitableviewcontroller-doesnt-work-properly-in-xcode-4-2) with creating tableviewcontroller

I have conducted a few more tests and it seems that ARC caused my problems. I have created a few projects like:

- creating a simple view table without xib in controller
- creating a table view using uiviewcontroller without xib
- creating a table view using uiviewcontroller with xib

I tried to scroll down the table, in each case program was crashed. 
Second, I set the delegate properly but I cannot use method didSelectRowAtIndexPath, it's wired that datasource methods worked well.

Here is a stack after my program crashed when I tried to scroll down the table cells.

```
> (gdb) bt
> #0  0x0156009b in objc_msgSend ()
> #1  0x07821800 in ?? ()
> #2  0x000ad589 in -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] ()
> #3  0x00098dfd in -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] ()
> #4  0x000a7851 in -[UITableView layoutSubviews] ()
> #5  0x00052322 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] ()
> #6  0x013bde72 in -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] ()
> #7  0x01d6692d in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
> #8  0x01d70827 in CA::Layer::layout_if_needed ()
> #9  0x01cf6fa7 in CA::Context::commit_transaction ()
> #10 0x01cf8ea6 in CA::Transaction::commit ()
> #11 0x01d9237a in CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch ()
> #12 0x01d921af in CA::Display::TimerDisplayLink::callback ()
> #13 0x01390966 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
> #14 0x01390407 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
> #15 0x012f37c0 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
> #16 0x012f2db4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
> #17 0x012f2ccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
> #18 0x012a5879 in GSEventRunModal ()
> #19 0x012a593e in GSEventRun ()
> #20 0x00013a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
> #21 0x00002588 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffed80) at /Users/lsd/Development/iPhone/MyTableView/MyTableView/main.m:16
> #22 0x000024e5 in start () (gdb)
```

I have created the same projects with the same lines of code with unchecked ARC, then everything start working like a charm.

John

Comment: Make sure you set the delegate properly, to the UITableViewController. self.tableView.delegate = self; and make sure the UITableViewController conforms to the <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

Comment: Did you set your table view's delegate?

Comment: I tried to set the delegate in UITableViewController's method viewDidLoad. Correct me, if I am wrong, but by setting self.tableView.delegate in controller isn't a bad idea? Shouldn't be setting it somehow in the view? For me it is a little bit strange that dataSource is working ok.

Thanks for helping me.


John

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's not needed, but try implementing a willSelectRowAtIndexPath method and just return indexPath there. And make sure that you are using a didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and NOT didDeselectRowAtindexPath. Once I spent a few hours looks for that error

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with doing it that way. What are you using, storyboard or xib's.

Comment: Whats in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I am sure I am using didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and without implementing method willSelectRowAtIndexPath it should be working. I am using neither storyboard or xib. When I created the table view controller I deselected option 'with XIB for user interface'. Of course I can build XIB for table view to fix the problem, but I was sure it can be implemented by doing as I described.

Comment: In didSelectRowAtIndexPath I have just put NSLog(@"test") before implementing next lines of code.

Comment: You are missing this method. numberOfSectionsInTableView

Comment: When I want to have only one session in the table view I may leave this method unimplemented because as sdk documentation says the method by default returns 1. I know that the problem is in delegate, but the question is still open, where should I set it to make the program to work.

Comment: UITableViewController automatically sets the UIViewController as the delegate and data source for the embedded UITableView. Anyway, this is definitely an odd issue, as I have the code you have and it's working fine for me. Are those two code pieces the only two places you've modified code or have you removed or changed anything else?

Comment: Oh, by the way, just as a response to your comment earlier: controllers should be the delegates and data source/something of views. This is standard for the Model-View-Controller design pattern that is commonly used in iOS. All views do is display the data. Controllers are the ones that read/create/other the data and pass it to the views as well as mange those views.

Comment: I have done a few simple steps without adding anything special to the code. I am right now suprised that the code is working for you and for me isn't. What xcode and os version do you use?

Comment: Update your question with the entirety of MyTableViewController.m. Something odd is going on and it's not in the code you have cherry picked for us.

Answer (score 0):

i think u are missed this Delegate
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;//Number of section in the tableview;
}

Comment: The question is where should I set the delegate? I tried to do it in each lifecycle method in tableviewcontroller without success. I think the best way is to repeat my steps in xcode and find out on your own eyes that something is wrong with tableviewcontroller template. Don't you think that Apple giving a simple template forgot to put one line to make delegate to work or didn't foresee that someone may use uitableviewcontroller template without xib?

Answer (score 0):

This is a project without xib and table was created within controller.

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UIViewController
<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *myTableView;

@end 


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myTableView    =   [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    self.myTableView.dataSource =   self;
    self.myTableView.delegate   =   self;

    [self.view addSubview:self.myTableView];
}
#pragma mark - UIViewTable DataSource methods



-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *result = nil;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyTableViewCellId";

    result =    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(result == nil)
    {
        result = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    result.textLabel.text   =   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %ld",(long)indexPath.row];


    return result;
}
```